# IBM Blockchain Cloud Service is not Approved

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-blockchain

I created one Blockchain service on **IBM cloud** on the 14th of Oct. But it was not approved till.
It's showing text, `will notify you by email when the service is available`. 
Does anyone have an idea about how many days it will take to approve?

Any help will be appreciated!!

[image]

Comment: You should contact IBM Support

Comment: let me rephrase, you have to contact IBM Support